# Wordpress: On get template, Parts not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7

I'm trying to redirect some of my posts from Single.php template to my training-v2 custom template using the code below, but the `get_template_part` is not working.

My templates are in the order of

`themes/theme/templates/training-v2.php`

`themes/theme/single.php`

Can anyone help with the `get_template_part` structure?

```php
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $custom_arr = array(6647,6794,6796);
    if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $custom_arr)) {
        get_template_part( 'themes/theme/templates', 'training-v2' );
    }
    else {
       get_template_part( 'theme/content', 'single' ); 
    }

endwhile; else :

    get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'index' );

endif;
?>
```

Comment: can you please share full path of files from root folder so I can help you to fix this issue.

Comment: hi, my full path is wp-content->themes->theme->templates->training-v2                                                         path for my single.php is wp-content->themes->theme->single.php

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the path you said (that's www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/ for your theme root), it must be:

```
get_template_part( 'templates/training', 'v2' );
```

[Codex wordpress get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

First parameter is the path from your theme root and the second parameter is for versioning this. The second is optional.
A footer or header is a great example why you need different versioning of the file. Allows a better templating structure.

Comment: can you explain me why there is comma separated between training and v2..?

Comment: Suposing that the path of your WP theme is:  
    `www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/templates/training-v2.php`    
Then the get template must be:  
    `get_template_part( 'templates/training', 'v2' );`
because the root of yor theme is /wp-content/themes/theme/

Comment: As single.php is the default file for single post you must put the code of your question, with the change I answered, after the get_header in the single.php file